# Safari 5.1.3 Position:Fixed Loading Scrolling Render Issue

Tags: css, safari, rendering, css-position

http://hungimage.herokuapp.com/ has a POC of an issue I am hitting while scrolling a loading page in Safari.
The image call at the bottom of the page is requesting an endpoint that will not return a response in order to keep the page loading and display the render issue.

While the page is loading and all assets have not been downloaded, if I scroll in Safari Version 5.1.3 (7534.53.10), the fixed position header will render incorrectly.
If you scroll up and down quickly in Safari, you should be able to detect the render issues.

I can't duplicate this in other browsers, and need a solution that doesn't adversely affect the position of absolutely positioned elements.
You can see a screencast here: http://www.flickr.com/photos/geoff/6861146330/

Am I missing something with the position:fixed?

---

Update:

---

This appears to be a legit Safari bug.
If you have page with a hung (forever loading - example here: geoffreymoller.no.de) image open in one tab in Safari 5.1.4, and a site with a fixed header in another tab (facebook, other examples here: http://webdesignledger.com/inspiration/22-examples-of-fixed-position-navigation-in-web-design), if you scroll in the fixed header site, the header will display render issues.

Comment: Not happening on my iMac Safari 534.54.16

Comment: same here not happening in any browsers.. and i just downloaded latest ver of safari 5.1.4 no issues. But i dont have 5.1.3. so i cant say anything because you are facing the problem in that particular browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Two things to bulletproof the code;

Make the div:

```
<div id="fixed"></div>
```

The semantic container in the page and add the following CSS declaration to the div#fixed rule

```
z-index:99;
```

Hope that helps Geoff.

Comment: Hi Desi - I added the z-index but that didn't affect the render issue. You can see it here: http://geoffreymoller.no.de/ . The fixed div is a header element, so it can't contain the rest of the page.